# Migrating from Joomla 2.5 to 3x Generating Errors

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

Trying to migrate some of the custom components which works well in Joomla 2.5.14 to Joomla 3.1.5, however getting some errors like - 404 component not found in Joomla Backend & other errors in frontend

Is there any migration guide from Jooma 2.5 to 3x series, of what changes need to be done in custom components

Front End Section of Site
1st error

```
   Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in forms.php
```

2nd error

```
   Warning: require_once(com_formsDScontroller.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in forms.php
```

3rd error

```
  Fatal error: require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'com_formsDScontroller.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in forms.php
```

Been all errors showing forms.php, it is

```
   <?php
   defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
   require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php' );
   if ($controller = JRequest::getWord('controller')) {
$path = JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controllers'.DS.$controller.'.php';
if (file_exists($path)) {
    require_once $path;
} else {
    $controller = '';
}
     }
   $classname   = 'FormsController'.$controller;
   $controller  = new $classname();
   $controller->execute( JRequest::getVar( 'layout' ) );
   $controller->redirect();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

From the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2)

> The DS constant has been removed. If you really need it you can use
>   DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead.

[Similar Question](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2720756)