# Joomla 3.0 DS does not work(Use of undefined constant DS)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

Joomla 3.0 DS does not work. It has been removed. I get

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in
```

How can I fix this?

[Similar Question](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2720756)

[Migrating from Joomla 2.5 to 3x Generating Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502882/joomla-2-5-to-3x-migration-getting-errors/18502925#18502925)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the below line

```
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

From the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2).

> The DS constant has been removed. If you really need it you can use
>   DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead.

Also there is a [plugin](http://digitaldisseny.com/en/joomla-extensions/solve-undefined-ds-constant-joomla-3-error) to fix this issue.

You can find the full list here.

[Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3 and Joomla Platform 12.2](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2)

Comment: You can also for the most part just not use DS and instead just put a forward slash in the file path: http://ajh.us/4

Comment: using the forward slash is OS dependant

Comment: In 2013 (and well before) forward slash is not a problem on windows except in very specific and limited situations most of which would not occur in normal extensions.

Comment: This is a nice workaround for older components, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need this: `if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', '/');`